# UITextField Subclass not calling shouldChangeText(in range:replacementText:)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextinput

I have a subclass of `UITextField` that works in all respects except that the overridden method `shouldChangeText(in range:replacementText:)` is not being called. I am trying to make a field that permits the user to enter only valid decimal numbers, and got that working in the equivalent delegate method, but since I will be using this in many places I want to just subclass it once.

My entire class is

```
class FWNumberField: FWTextField {

    override func shouldChangeText(in range: UITextRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == ".", self.text == nil || self.text!.isEmpty || self.text!.contains(".") {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }    
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) { return false }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Where `FWTextField` is a subclass of `UITextField` that adds a simple `inputAccessoryView` that has a "Done" button, and the keyboard is restricted to a decimal keyboard in my Storyboard.

My storyboard and IBOutlet both have their types set to `FWNumberField`. Any thoughts on why the method isn't being called? The docs say it should be.

Comment: `UITextFieldDelegate` has a method called `shouldChangeCharactersIn....`  Not `UITextField`, though.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield

Comment: @danh They both have the method, with slightly different naming

Comment: Can you provide an Apple doc link?

Comment: @danh https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614495-shouldchangetext

Comment: I see. The discussion says it's called on the delegate. Not sure what object that is.

Comment: I interpreted the docs as this being the method that calls the delegate. It's a protocol that all the text input views adopt (UITextField, UITextView, NSTextView, etc.)

Comment: I agree this is not working as designed.  Perhaps you could submit at bug at https://bugreport.apple.com/